# Writing Spark functions that take Column arguments and return a Column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to write a `yeardiff` function that works similarly to `datediff`.  `yeardiff` should take two `Column` arguments and return a Column with the number of years between those parameter Columns.

Let's use the following sample data:

```
val testDf = Seq(
  ("2016-09-10", "2001-08-10"),
  ("2016-04-18", "2010-05-18"),
  ("2016-01-10", "2013-08-10")
)
  .toDF("first_datetime", "second_datetime")
  .withColumn("first_datetime", $"first_datetime".cast("timestamp"))
  .withColumn("second_datetime", $"second_datetime".cast("timestamp"))
```

We can run this to get the date difference:

```
testDf.withColumn("num_days", datediff(col("first_datetime"), col("second_datetime")))
```

I want to be able to run this:

```
testDf.withColumn("num_years", yeardiff(col("first_datetime"), col("second_datetime")))
```

I tried to define a `yeardiff` function with the necessary method signature and didn't get anywhere:

```
def yeardiff(end: Column, start: Column): Column = {
  // what do I do here
}
```

Here is a hacked transformation solution that I came up with and don't like:

```
def yearDiff(end: String, start: String)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val c = s"${end}_${start}_datediff"
  df
    .withColumn(c, datediff(col(end), col(start)))
    .withColumn("yeardiff", col(c) / 365)
}
```

EDIT

I started digging into the Spark source code to see how `datediff` works.  Here is [the `datediff` function definition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7a7ce272fe9a703f58b0180a9d2001ecb5c4b8db/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L2516):

```
def datediff(end: Column, start: Column): Column = withExpr { DateDiff(end.expr, start.expr) }
```

Here is [the `DateDiff` case class](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7a7ce272fe9a703f58b0180a9d2001ecb5c4b8db/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/datetimeExpressions.scala#L1329):

```
case class DateDiff(endDate: Expression, startDate: Expression)
  extends BinaryExpression with ImplicitCastInputTypes {

  override def left: Expression = endDate
  override def right: Expression = startDate
  override def inputTypes: Seq[AbstractDataType] = Seq(DateType, DateType)
  override def dataType: DataType = IntegerType

  override def nullSafeEval(end: Any, start: Any): Any = {
    end.asInstanceOf[Int] - start.asInstanceOf[Int]
  }

  override def doGenCode(ctx: CodegenContext, ev: ExprCode): ExprCode = {
    defineCodeGen(ctx, ev, (end, start) => s"$end - $start")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may solve your problem:

```
def yearDiff(end: Column, start: Column): Column = {
  datediff(end, start)/365
}
```

Comment: This is a good work-around, but you need to change the argument order to `datediff(end, start)/365`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the built in year function and a udf to adjust for cases where the month has not past.

```
            def yeardiff(end: Column, start: Column): Column = {
              def getAdjustment(monthStart : Int, monthEnd : Int, dayStart : Int, dayEnd : Int) : Int = {
                if (monthEnd>monthStart) return -1
                if (monthStart==monthEnd && dayEnd > dayStart) return -1
                else return 0
              }
              val udfGetAdjustment =  udf[Int,Int,Int,Int,Int](getAdjustment)
              val adj = udfGetAdjustment(month(start),month(end),dayofmonth(start),dayofmonth(end))
              year(end)  - year(start) + adj
            }
```